# Is there any SDK like Metaio and Vuforia for iOS platform, I want to create app like IKEA Catalog or Snapshop?

Tags: objective-c, augmented-reality, vuforia, wikitude, metaio

I want to create an iOS app just like IKEA Catalog or Snapshop, for POC i have used these AR SDK Metaio and Vuforia but now these AR SDK are not available, please help me if any such kind of AR SDK is available

Answer (score 1):

Vuforia remains available and is being actively developed. iOS support for it continues unabated.

You may be confused because the Vuforia project was purchased from Qualcomm by PTC at the end of last year - but there's been no indication that they're closing the SDK. In fact, development seems to have been more aggressive with updates coming more frequently.

More information [is here.](https://developer.vuforia.com/)

Downloads for the current release for Android, iOS and Unity [are here.](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk)